# Are toast columns compressed also in shared_buffers?

Tags: postgresql, compression

Reading here I cannot find a clear answer:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html

I need to know if setting storage to `EXTERNAL` for a particular column, I can gain a little performance. Most of my data is retrieved from `SHARED_BUFFERS`.

I'm curious to know if decompression is done for every query working on that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are.

`shared_buffers` is block-oriented, and stored in the same format as on-disk.

This is generally good for performance, since the decompression is very fast, and the compression means that more fits in `shared_buffers`. The only case it might hurt is if you have enough storage to fit the whole dataset in `shared_buffers` uncompressed too.

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of memory dedicated to postgresql and some xml data of few megabytes. A lot of queryes are eating cps, so I'm going to uncompress this data. Thank you.